# How to switch back to previous window on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, xcode

As a long time Windows users I'm used to switch between two windows using keyboard. Now at Mac I just can't figure out how to do that!

**Command-Tab** works nicely between apps, but how to do the same within one application having several windows open? Especially when using XCode? For example within Firefox you can do **control-tab** and control-shift-tab to navigate between tabs. Doesn't work with XCode, not between two different open projects.

Doing **4-fingers-down**, looking at screen, finding the previous window and clicking on it with mouse takes waaaay too long time. It interrupts whatever I was doing, distracts from whatever I was thinking about and starts annoying me - enough to write this desperate call for help in StackOverflow :)

There's got to be a secret handsha... keyboard combination!

Comment: The answers as given, Command-\` are correct for most, if not all, keyboard layouts. (You can also use that to go backwards in the application switcher, after you hit Command-Tab.) I wonder if layouts that have no \` have a different shortcut like, for what I've heard, the Apple-French layout -- http://store.apple.com/ca/product/MB110C/A

Answer (score 15):

Before this is moved to superuser, the shortcut you're looking for is command-`

Comment: I don't think so, looking for smthng else.

In my system that key combination does cycle inside one app windows, but goes only FORWARD. I want especially switch between current and previous window(s). Right now I have 6 open wins in XCode, so that's 5 keys AND knowing how many wins I have open AND counting the presses. If I got to actually look at and select windon, my concentration disappears. Yes, easy to distract!

Comment: Try command-shift-`.

Answer (score 8):

> Command-Tab works nicely between apps,
>   but how to do the same within one
>   application having several windows
>   open?

I was also a bit annoyed at this, until I found the "**Move focus to the next window in application**" keyboard shortcut option (under System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Keyboard & Text Input).

I set it to Cmd-§ (⌘§) myself (which is close to Cmd-Tab and I couldn't think of anything better). Shift-Cmd-§ cycles in the opposite direction. It's not ideal, but sort of tolerable for me, although I'd still prefer Cmd-Tab toggling between all *windows*.

There are also 3rd party utilities that improve OS X's window switching capabilities; check out [**Witch**](http://www.manytricks.com/witch/) for instance. I haven't tried these myself though.

Answer (score 5):

When you have to window active (focused), do Command-~.

Comment: Is there any keyboard layout that has the tilde on the lower part of the key? (Like one does not need Shift to type a tilde?)

Comment: Usually default keyboard shortcuts are designed for US layout, you could check that. Might mean you have to type blind or buy extra keyboard with US layout.

Comment: By Command-~, he means Command-Shift-` I think.

Comment: Heh, with this keyboard shift-` is impossible :) It's Command-Shift-´to make Command-`, if that is more clear. Also Command-~ is actually Command-Alt-¨. Guess I'll have to live without (some) shortcuts and just get on with the remaining ones. Thanx anyway!

Comment: Sorry, looks like this system uses (removed) character for text formatting! I was trying to type what Ziggamorph shows above. The latter one.

Answer (score 5):

[Hyperswitch](https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch) (free) and [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/) ($14, though more configurable) allow doing this.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed and also what the author needed!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a custom shortcut, I noticed that macOS Sierra seems to automatically map Shift-[shortcut here] to the reverse of your original shortcut, when it makes sense (e.g. anything that involves "next" probably has a corresponding "previous" version). Possibly because someone expected that a user would expect this to happen?

So if you look in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard you'll only find "Move focus to next window" bound by default to Command-` and this is why Command-Shift-` triggers "Move focus to last window."

Set "Move focus to next window" to any other combination that doesn't involve Shift, and Shift-[that combination] will do "Move focus to last window".

Answer (score 2):

I found this decision tree for finding the right shortcut:

[Decision tree for last window shortcut on mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CHRJ.png)

[image: Decision tree for last window shortcut on mac]

The main decisions are:

- Was it in a different Program from the one you want to switch from?
- Is the other Window on the same Desk?
- Do you use a "QWERTY" Keyboard layout?
- Is this the previous window you used?

It shows that it's not easy. The source ([xpt.de](https://xpt.de/mac-toggle-last-window/)) choose to use a third party app called [Hyperswitch](https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great decision tree!

Comment: The decision tree is inaccurate. If the previous window from a different app (first answer is yes, then done) has another window in the current desktop, CMD+Tab will switch to that window instead.

Comment: Dang @GeorgeLeung - I think you're right. We should use this tree as a base and expand it, so it's also covering that case ;-)

Comment: I think there's even more complication when a second monitor is involved.

Answer (score 0):

To switch to the *previous* / *next* window of **the same** tab (macOS):

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘ `</kbd>
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘ Shift ⇧ `</kbd>

The order depends on the keyboard layout (UK / US).

---

Based on the answers from: [Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/308967#308967):

- [UK Keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193938/422012)
- [US Keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/247863/422012)

Answer (score -1):

try "cmd" + "<" within xcode.
It works with my keyboard -
KK